# LibGDX strange status bar in background [BUG]

Tags: android, libgdx, statusbar

I released an app and I noticed that some devices has a strange "bug" which I don't know if it's caused by Android, me or LibGDX.

That bug is related to status bar, normally app let you see the bar (time, battery percentage ...). In my app the statusbar shouldn't be showed but it seems to exist in some devices.

What is strange is that the bar isn't the same of the device but a general bar with random time and battery percentage. Sometimes the bar showed is an older Android version.

My XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package=".android"
    android:versionCode="4"
    android:versionName="1.3">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="13"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/GdxTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"

            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" />

        <activity
            android:name=".AndroidLauncher"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"

            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Style.xml :

```
<style name="GdxTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>

</style>
```

Comment: Post your manifest. This has to do with the theme selected for the Activity. There's a theme that has a transparent status bar, which sounds like what you're describing.

Comment: @Tenfour04 This is my xml

Answer (score 0):

The `application` element has the `@style/GdxTheme` set, which removes the status bar, among other things. But then in the `activity` element, you have overridden the theme with `@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen`, which does show a transparent status bar.

You should remove `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"`, and then if you need to customize it, modify the `GdxTheme` in `res/values/styles.xml` to have the characteristics you want.

Comment: I set  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" because the default theme let the status bar showed so I thought to solve the problem with android theme. Maybe I have solved the problem, let me check but I think you are right

Comment: I posted my style.xml how could I fix? I can't find a solution